# Solving a complicated, non-polynomial dispersion relation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, symbolic

I am quite new to Mathematica, so I apologise if the following question is very basic; I can't seem to find an appropriate answer anywhere!

I am trying to solve a quite complicated dispersion relation (see below) for some frequency $\omega$ which, in general, may be complex, and is a function of the variables $k_x$, $k_y$, $k_z$, as well as the numerical constants $T$, $B$ and $\tau$. I would like to be able to plot the real and imaginary parts of the solution $\omega$ for a large range of values of $k_x$, $k_y$ and $k_z$ given the values of $T$, $B$, $\tau$, e.g., create a contour plot of $\omega$ in the $(k_x,k_y)$ plane.

When I have been tackling simpler problems of this type with Mathematica, I have been using `Solve[(* dispersion relation *) ==0, [\omega]]` to obtain `[\omega] = [\omega][kx,ky,kz,T,B,\[tau]]`, which then will allow me to produce the desired output by simply plotting this function with respect to the given variables for values of $T$, $B$, etc. However, I immediately run into a problem in the more complicated case that I am considering, as Mathematica is unable to solve the dispersion relation using `Solve` or `Reduce` given its complexity, and non-polynomial nature.

What is the best way to approach this problem while keeping the solution method sufficiently general that I can still plot $\omega$ as a function of $k_x$, $k_y$ and/or $k_z$ for various values of $B$, $T$ and $\tau$? From what I have gathered by searching online, an appropriate way would be to use `NSolve` to create a table for $\omega$ for various values of $k_x$, $k_y$, and $k_z$. However, I would like to also retain the dependence numerical constants $T$, $B$ and $\tau$, but I can't see a good way of doing this without simply trying to use `Solve`, as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

For completeness, the dispersion relation is as follows:
\begin{align}
0=&\zeta^2\left\{k_x^2 + k_y^2 -2\left( \zeta^2 - \frac{1}{2} \right)\left[1+\zeta \mathcal{Z} - \zeta \zeta_*  - \zeta_* \left( \zeta^2 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \mathcal{Z}\right]\right\} \\
&- \left[ \frac{1}{2}(k_x^2 + k_y^2) - 2 \zeta_d \zeta_* \right]\left\{ 1-  2\tau\left( \zeta^2 - \frac{1}{2} \right)\left[1+\zeta \mathcal{Z} - \zeta \zeta_*  - \zeta_* \left( \zeta^2 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \mathcal{Z}\right]\right\} \\
&+\zeta \zeta_d \left[(k_x^2 + k_y^2)\tau -1 \right]\left\{1 - \zeta_* \mathcal{Z} +2\left( \zeta^2 - \frac{1}{2} \right)\left[1+\zeta \mathcal{Z} - \zeta \zeta_*  - \zeta_* \left( \zeta^2 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \mathcal{Z}\right] \right\}
\end{align}
where
$$ \zeta = \frac{\omega}{2k_z}, \quad \zeta_* = \frac{k_y T}{2 k_z}, \quad \zeta_d =\frac{k_y B}{2 k_z},  $$
with $T$, $B$ and $\tau$ simply numerical constants, while $\mathcal{Z}$ is the plasma dispersion function
$$ \mathcal{Z}(\zeta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int \text{d}x \: \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-\zeta},  $$
which, in Mathematica, can be expressed as `I*Sqrt[Pi]*Exp[-[\zeta]^2]*(1+I*Erfi[[\zeta]])`. The presence of this function is the reason that the dispersion relation is non-polynomial, and is also badly-behaved for certain values of $\zeta$.

In `Mathematica`, I've written this up as:

```
D3D[p_, kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]^2 ((kx^2 + ky^2) - 2 (zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]^2 - 1/2)*bracket[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]) - (1/2*(kx^2 + ky^2) -2*zetastar[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*zetadrift[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]) (1 - 2*t*(zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]^2 - 1/2)*bracket[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]) + zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*zetadrift[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*((kx^2 + ky^2)*t - 1) (1 - zetastar[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*zfunction[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t] + 2 (zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]^2 - 1/2)*bracket[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t])
```

where:

```
zeta[p_, kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := (I*p)/(2*Abs[kz])

zetastar[p_, kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := (ky*T)/(2*Abs[kz])

zetadrift[p_, kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := (ky*B)/(2*Abs[kz])

zfunction[p_, kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := I*Sqrt[Pi]*Exp[-zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]^2]*(1 + I*Erfi[zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]])

bracket[p_, kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := 1 + zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*zfunction[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t] - zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*zetastar[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t] - zetastar[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]*(zeta[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]^2 - 1/2)*zfunction[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t]
```

and $p = i\omega$ is the complex growth rate. Apologies for the poor formatting.

---

Edit: I have tried using the `FindRoot` function in order to solve the problem. I extract the real and imaginary parts of the solution using

```
Resols[kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := Re[p /. FindRoot[D3D[p, kz, kx, ky,T, B, t], {p, 0}]]
Imsols[kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := Im[p /. FindRoot[D3D[p, kz, kx, ky, T, B, t], {p, 0}]]
```

and then plot the solution as follows

```
kx = 0;
T = 1;
B = 0;
t=1;

kymin = 0.006;
kymax = 10; 
kzmin = 0.01;
kzmax = 3; 

stabilityboundary[kz_, kx_, ky_, T_, B_, t_] := kz - 
  Sqrt[ 1/(8 (1 + t))*(1 - (kx^2 + ky^2)*t)^2/(1 + (kx^2 + ky^2))*ky^2/(kx^2 + ky^2)]

p1 = ContourPlot[
  Max[Resols[kz, ky, ky, T, B, t], 0],
  {ky, kymin, kymax},
  {kz, kzmin, kzmax},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
  Contours -> {Automatic, 50},
  ContourStyle -> None,
  Exclusions -> None,
  FrameLabel -> {{Style[
      "k_z", 18], 
     None}, {Style[
      "k_y", 18], ""}},
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"],
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 1}}], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> Automatic,
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision,
  GridLinesStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}
  ];

p2 = ContourPlot[
   {stabilityboundary[kz, kx, ky, T, B, t] == 0, 
    kz - ky/Sqrt[ky^2 + kx^2]*Sqrt[B/T] == 0},
   {ky, kymin, kymax},
   {kz, kzmin, kzmax},
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
   Contours -> Automatic,
   ContourStyle -> {{White, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}, {Gray, 
      Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}},
   Exclusions -> None,
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"],
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotRangePadding -> Automatic,
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision,
   GridLinesStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}
   ];


Rasterize[Show[p1,p2]]

Clear[kymin, kymax, kzmin, kzmax]

Clear[kz, kx, ky, B]
```

which has output

[image]

The `FindRoots` method only appears to work well for a particular portion of the $(k_y,k_z)$ space where the $\mathcal{Z}$ function is relatively well behaved. From an analytical treatment of the dispersion relation, I expect everything below the white dashed line to be positive, and everything above it zero or negative. This clearly isn't the case, meaning that `FindRoot` is failing in various portions of the space. This was the original reason for my question; I haven't found another good way of doing this.

Comment: One can use `FindRoot`, although that finds a single root at a time based on an initial guess, so it can be hard to know that you've found all the roots given a particular set of a parameters.  An alternative is to use `ContourPlot`, then extract the points from the plot and feed them to `FindRoot` as initial guesses in order to refine the roots. If you want help, though, it would be helpful for you to edit your post with the equation in copy-and-paste-able *Mathematica* code. That way, we don't have to type it out ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @march, it's greatly appreciated!  I did try using FindRoot, but it either only re-produced a subset of the solutions I would expect, or didn't produce any solutions at all due to poor initial guesses. 

I've updated the post with the dispersion relation written as ```Mathematica``` code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: If your dispersion relation is derived from a differential equation that can be seen as an eigenvalue problem, it might be easier to discretize the original differential equation and treat it as numerical eigenvalue problem. This would give you basically all the roots as eigenvalue spectrum (depending on the numerical resolution).

Comment: @barone, that's a great suggestion, but unfortunately is not the case for the system that I am considering.